# Cassandra: allow filtering vs multiple B2B queries on partition key

Tags: python, database, cassandra, nosql, bigdata

I have this query

> Show the 25 movies with the highest mean rating between 01/01/2012  and 31/05/2012.

By the nature of the problem I think it's not possible to create a table that doesn't require allow filtering.

I design the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS popular_recipes 
(
    start_date date,
    rating float,
    mov_id int,
    mov_name text,

    PRIMARY KEY (rating, start_date, mov_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(start_date DESC,rec_id ASC)
```

Rating has values 5, 4.5,4 .... 0.

I read that Allow Filtering should be avoided so I thought I will query iteratively on rating. If rating=5 doesn't return 30 rows as result, then query for rating=4.5 is executed, etc. until I have 25 rows or until there is no possible rating value.

First of all, am I right that this query can't be mapped to a table in a way so that we avoid allow filtering?

If that's true, what should I prefer, allow filtering or the solution I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I took a shot at this.

**tl;dr**

Your approach w/ ALLOW FILTERING might be the way to go here.

I went through a few table designs, and ultimately came up with this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS popular_movie_ratings (
    half_year_bucket TEXT,
    rating_date date,
    rating float,
    movie_id int,
    movie_name text,
    user_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY (half_year_bucket, movie_id, rating, rating_date, user_id)
);
```

So the idea, is that we're storing all ratings taken for half of a year as our partition.  This *could* grow to be big, so if this were a real use case, we'd likely have to bucket on something smaller (quarter or month).

Then, we're clustering on `movie_id`, `rating`, `rating_date`, and `user_id`.

I INSERTed 10 rows with data for 6 movies, and came up with this query:

```
> SELECT movie_name, AVG(rating) FROm popular_movie_ratings 
WHERE half_year_bucket='2023A'
GROUP BY half_year_bucket, movie_id;

 movie_name                                  | system.avg(rating)
---------------------------------------------+--------------------
                Highlander 2: The Quickening |               1.45
                          Back to the Future |               4.85
                      Hot Tub Time Machine 2 |                3.8
                          The Imitation Game |            4.76667
                                   Goldeneye |                3.5
 Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides |                  2

(6 rows)
```

So the problem here, is that I can't enforce ordering of the results by average rating.  I think your ALLOW FILTERING solution might be ok, as long as the cluster doesn't have many nodes and isn't dealing with TBs of data.